# Rails with jQuery + AJAX fundamentals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I've been given a task to do a simple Task Manager on Ruby On Rails. It's pretty simple for me but there is one issue. Everything has to be "ajaxified" and data should be passed around in JSON.

How I do this right now.

On index.html.erb

I'm creating a simple form with these parameters:

```
<%= form_for(Task.new, remote: true, :html => {:'data-type' => 'json'}) do |f| %>
```

In TasksController:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController

respond_to :json

def create
@project = Project.find(params[:task][:project_id])


if @task = @project.tasks.create!(name: params[:task][:name], description: params[:task][:description])
respond_with(@task)
else  
flash[:error] = 'error'  
end
```

and inside  on index.htm.erb I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#new_task").bind('ajax:success', function(evt, data, status, xhr){


    var row = ('<tr id="task.id"><td>'+data.name+'</td>'+'<td>'+data.description+'</td>'+'<td>'+data.state+'</td>'+'<td><%= link_to "delete task", task_path(task.id), :method => "delete", remote:true, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %></td></tr>');
    $(row).insertAfter("#tasks_table tr:first");

    slicer($("#total"));
    slicer($("#active"));

}); });

$("#new_task").bind("ajax:beforeSend", function(event,xhr,status){
    $(this)[0].reset();
});
```

And now I'd like to give some explanation about how this might work(my personal thoughts)

by specyfing remote: true, I'm telling the form to submit data in input on server via Unobtrusive Javascript, rails 3 feature. It sends an usual hash in my example this is params[:task][:name] etc, but it expects to get back JSON because I did set :html => {:'data-type' => 'json'}) (is this correct syntax?). Now in my TasksController class I have the respond_to :json, it means that controller WILL answer those requests, where data-type json is specified, with json, because respond_with is smart enough to do to_json on object you are doing respond_with.

Am I right in all those assumptions?

So the question is if we can use js.erb and json.erb(yes?) do you need to return the json at all ?

Comment: this are several question, I propose some answer below. let me know what aspects I could clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe going a step back helps.

With AJAX form, the submit event goes through JavaScript first, and does not trigger the browser to invoke a POST '/data.json'.

If you look at the HTML that is generated by Rails with the `remote: true` option, you probably see a "onsubmit()" or similar `callback`. It is also the JavaScript, that processes a 'success' or 'error' event. I like the jQuery documentation for this:  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Your question is also somewhat opinionated, because JavaScript libraries such as Backbone.js, Ember.js or Angular, allow to fine-tune the process chain of a form submit even further.